# Minimal polynomial of one value and multiplicity one implies matrix diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T \in L(V,V)$ a linear operator with minimal polynomial $m_T (x) = (x- \lambda)$ where $\lambda$ is in a field $\mathbb{K}$. Show that $T$ is diagonalizable.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how the minimal polynomial is defined? Using its definition the answer to your question is immediate.

Comment: Yes, it is true. The definition of minimal polynomial of a linear operator T in L(V,V), is the monic polynomial m_T(x) of lowest degree such that m_T (T)(v)=0 for all v in V.
Using answer of Omnomnomnom and your question I have try this approach: Aut_T (\lambda) = Ker(T-\lambda)=Ker(m_T(T)) so v in Ker (m_T(T)), for all v in V, wich implies dim Aut_T(\lambda)=n. Therefore T is diagonalizable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $m_T(x) = (x - \lambda)$, then $m_T(T) = T - \lambda I = 0$.  So, $T = \lambda I$.  So, $T$ is a multiple of the identity operator, and is therefore diagonalizable.